# Create a list of lists in python

Tags: python

I have a list

```
a=['10,20,30','30,45,90','40,56,80']
```

each element of the list is a string. I want to make a list of lists, such that it will look like this:

```
a=[[10,20,30],[30,45,90],[40,56,80]]
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `split` as follows:

```
b = [map(int, i.split(',')) for i in a]

>>> print b
[[10,20,30],[30,45,90],[40,56,80]]
```

The `split` method splits the string on the specified sub-string, in this case: `','`. A `split` without any arguments, such as `string.split()` will split the string on a whitespace character and then return a list.

Comment: your code will produce list of strings not numbers
[['10', '20', '30'], ['30', '45', '90'], ['40', '56', '80']]

Comment: @vaibhaw, Thank you. I have updated my answer. It gives `ints` now.

Answer (score 2):

`.split` splits the string into strings, so we'll convert each one to `int` after splitting.

```
>>> a = ['10,20,30','30,45,90','40,56,80']
>>> [[int(y) for y in x.split(',')] for x in a]
[[10, 20, 30], [30, 45, 90], [40, 56, 80]]
```